# линковка после компиляции, без стандартных библиотек

Tags: c, ассемблер, стек

```
#include "calls.h"

enum { size = 1024 };

char expression[size];
char result[size];
const char *exp_cc;
const char *res_cc = result;

int chars_to_num(const char *s, int *num);
int solve_polska(const char *s);

int main()
{
        int i;
        int num = 0;
        sys_read(0, expression, size);
        for(i = 0; expression[i]; i++){
                exp_cc = expression + i;
                i += chars_to_num(exp_cc, &num);
        }
        return 0;
}

int chars_to_num(const char *s, int *num)
{
        int i = -1;
        for(; *s >= 0x30 && *s <= 0x39; s++, i++)
                *num = (*num) * 10 + (*s - 0x30);
        return i;
}
```

Пишу программу для решения произвольного выражения где на входе есть цифры и сиволы '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')'.
На входе будет строка, пытаюсь для начала сделать функцию для преобразования строкового числа в конкретное число.

Программа не может использовать библиотечные возможности, у меня есть только аналоги системных вызовов write и read, а так же ассемблерный модуль который вызвыает функцию main.

При компиляции всех модулей для получения объектных файлов всё впорядке, ошибок нет. Так же sys_read(мой read) и sys_write(мой write) работают нормально.

Вот вопрос: при линковке командой **ld -m elf_i386 main.o start.o calls.o -o main** выдаются ошибки:

**ld: main.o: in function `main':**

**main.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail_local'**

**ld: main: hidden symbol `__stack_chk_fail_local' isn't defined**

**ld: final link failed: bad value**

Я понимаю что дело в функции, если её закоментировать, то всё соберётся и нормально запустится, просто причитается строка, запишется в expression[size], пройдется циклом по ней и завершится программа. Но не понимаю что не так и что не нравится линковщику при вызове этой функции.

UPD:

Я понял... int num = 0 нужно было объявить глобально... Но что мешало при объявлении внутри main я не понял.

Еще не совсем понимаю можно ли константному указателю присваивать указатель не константного массива, а так же можно ли передавать указатель неконстантного массива в функцию, которая ожидает константный указатель. Компилятор просто при этом не ругается и линковщик тоже, но насколько это правильно вообще делать.

Comment: Флаги сборки в студию, нет не влияет, это ограничение на этап компиляции, на деле же не существует никаких const

Comment: `-fno-stack-protector` в помощь

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в ключи сборки `-nostdlib` (Вообще, почитайте про этот флаг в [man gcc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) (стоит найти по ^F все упоминания `stdlib`))

Comment: @ori, gcc -m32 -Wall -c

Comment: @avp, -nostdlib позволил линковщику всё собрать даже с объявлением переменной внутри main. Может быть вы вкурсе что значит эта ошибка и что stdlib требовал? В 2 словах))

Comment: `__stack_chk_fail_local` -- это какая-то внутренняя переменная среды исполнения, которая нужна для контроля стека. Если с `-nostdlib` ошибка не исчезла, то попробуйте добавить флаги `-fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-check`

Comment: @avp, -nostdlib  флаг помог )